# Cannot remove underline nor change text color using a hyperlink

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, underline

I have a certain part of my text to have a hyperlink, but when I use the anchor element, use CSS to have text-decoration off, and change the color to `#987b74`, It does not work. Does anyone have any clue what is wrong? I've tried everything!

If needed, I can send my entire CSS, just let me know! Thank you for your help! :)

```css
header{
    background-image: url(banner1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-color: #FACABC;
    background-position: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: #FACABC;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    line-height: 5px;
}

.title{
    font-size: 500%;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FACABC;
    color: #987b74;
}

#homelink{
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 135%;
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    color: #FACABC;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ion-icon{
    padding-left: 6em;
    font-size: 41px;
    color: #987b74;
}

ion-icon:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

body{
    font-family: RedRock, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    background: #FACABC;
    z-index:1;
}

/* Nav bar*/
    
nav{

    z-index: 9999;
}

.container nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    
    
    font-size: 48px;
    padding-left: 7em; /* Centers "Home, About me, Socials, etc" text */
}

.container nav a{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #987b74;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.container nav ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li{
    width: 10%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: sticky;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
}

.container nav ul li:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
}   

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: white; /* Background of drop down */
    width: 75%;
    height: 110px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), -1px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    top: 75px;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{

    font-size: 31px;
    font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
    width: 75%;
}

.container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 75%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.container li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a:hover{
    color: #5E4C47;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container nav ul li ul.sub-nav a{
    padding: 0;
}

main h2{
    padding-right: 10em;
    padding-left: 10em;
}

main .learn-more{
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #FACABC;
  border: none;
  color: #987b74;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 275px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
}

main .learn-more span{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more span:after{
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

main .learn-more:hover span{
  padding-right: 25px;
}

main .learn-more:hover span:after{
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
} 

.video-trailer{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f8f8f8, #FACABC, #f8f8f8);
}

main ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
}

main h1{
    font-size: 60px;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    color: #987b74;
}

.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

table {
  font-family: primer, "Times New Roman", sans-sarif;
  color: #987b74;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table td, table th {
  padding: 8px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

table tr:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #987b74;
  font-size: 200%;

table td{
  border-top: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-right: 1px solid #987b74;
  text-align: center;

td:last-child{
    border-right: 0px;
}

.video-trailer h1{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #987b74;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="wrapper">
    <title>HighItsKy</title>
    <link href="highitsky.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/redrock" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/primer" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">     

<body>
    <header>
        <a id="homelink" href="index.html">
            <h2 id="homelink">HighItsKy</h2>
        </a>
        <br><br><br><br>
        <span class="title"><h1>HighItsKy</h1></span>
        <h2>part time streamer, full time vibe</h2>
        <br><br>
        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/highitsky/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitch"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://discord.gg/M2umXEhkNq" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://youtube.com/highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@highitsky" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-tiktok"></ion-icon></a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/highitsky_/" target="_blank"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></a>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
        <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="index.html">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <li>About Me
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="AboutMe.html">
                            <li>ABOUT</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Cloves.html">
                            <li>CLOVES</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Socials
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Socials.html">
                            <li>SOCIALS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="Contact.html">
                            <li>CONTACT</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <a href="Community.html">
                    <li>Community</li>
                </a>
                <a href="Partnerships.html">
                    <li>Partnerships</li>
                </a>
                <li>Support
                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                        <a href="Donate.html"><li>DONATE</li></a>
                        <a href="Merch.html"><li>MERCH</li></a>
                        <a href="Causes.html"><li>CAUSES</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header"></div>
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="backgroundcolor">
            <br>
            <a href="https://clovessyndrome.org/what-is-cloves/"><button class="learn-more"><span>LEARN MORE </span></button></a>
            <br><br><br><br><br>
        <div class="video-trailer">
            <br><br><br>
            <h2>If you are ever interested in supporting some causes monetarily or not, click the link below. I have comprised some of <a href="Causes.html" target="_blank">my favorite organizations</a>, including a few that I have used personally!</h2>
            <br><br><br><br><hr size="2" color="#987b74">
        </div>
            <footer>HighItsKy &copy; 2020 </footer>
        </div>
    </main>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is working - have you included your CSS code in the correct place?

Comment: @alekskorovin Hello! I think it may have something to do with the other hyperlink within the code. I added the full CSS if that helps- sorry, I'm new to this website and coding HTML in general!

Comment: There are several not-closed CSS rules in your code above styles for links. Please correct those: `
table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #987b74;
  font-size: 200%;
}
table td{
  border-top: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #987b74;
  border-right: 1px solid #987b74;
  text-align: center;
}`

Comment: @alekskorovin Oh my goodness thank you SO much. That fixed it right up!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aleks korovin in the comments:

There are several not-closed CSS rules in your code above styles for links. Please correct those:

```
table th { 
   padding-top: 12px; 
   padding-bottom: 12px; 
   text-align: center; 
   color: #987b74; 
   font-size: 200%; 
} 

table td { 
   border-top: 1px solid #987b74; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #987b74; 
   border-right: 1px solid #987b74; 
   text-align: center; 
}
```